# How to Add Temples in My Dotnet core Project

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, command-line-interface

I want to add following files in my project by using .net core cli. I am using .net core 2.1

```
class file(eg: test.cs)
controller(eg: testController.cs)
view(eg: MyView.cs)
```

How can i add this file in my project. Any one try to help me.
Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Read this article https://gavilan.blog/2018/04/28/asp-net-core-2-doing-scaffolding-with-dotnet-cli-aspnet-codegenerator/ by Felipe Gavilán

Example: `dotnet aspnet-codegenerator controller -name TestController`